# Component with workflow loads only once

Tags: presentation, workflow, components

In our project we have a home page and test home page. Both the pages have a component with two different data sources (based on same template- but content differs). Now the problem is when we make changes to the any of the two datasource item and publish it, based on which page gets loaded first the content in the specific datasource item is getting displayed for both the pages. (Eg: Loading the home page in browser first. Then both the home page and test page have same content of home page). Rendering method is hit only once for the first time. We are using workflow for the page. Not on component

Comment: Sounds like you have caching set on the component but you are not varying the cache by datasource. Can you check that?

Comment: Seems like you made a duplicate of home page as test home page, if you did that, change the data source of the item in test bags to reflect to the right data source

Comment: Thanks a million Richard. Some how vary by datasource resolved my issue. But the weird thing is caching was not set on component at all. Worklow on page level alone set.

Comment: Home page was not duplicated. And the datasource of both the home page and test home page are different
@Mahesh

Comment: Atlast found the issue.. caching was set on rendering level. Thanks a million Richard and Mahesh..